# Why aren't styles loading in second page in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Below is the part of screenshot of **mywebsite/index.php**, a PC site with NO jQuery Mobile (JQM), with all scripts and styles.

[image]

Below the screenshot of **mywebsite/mobile/options.php**, a page designed to be run on mobile browsers, having JQM.

[image]

Here is the HTML script for **Logout** button, actually an `ahchor` tag:

```
<a href="../logout.php" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-icon="delete" data-inline="true" data-ajax="false">Logout</a>
```

`..` refers to the main mywebsite folder out from mobile folder.

When I tap/click **Logout**, it should go to **mywebsite/index.php**, the PC site. And here's what shows up:

[image]

If I display the location using `alert(document.location);`, it shows - **mywebsite/mobile/options.php**.

I have to press **F5** to view the page as it should.

I know that this is happening because JQM loads the pages AJAXually and hence ignores all scripts and stylesheets outside of BODY tag. I know this question is duplicate of many questions in StackOverflow and I have tried my level best to find a solution, but can't find one.

How do I move to the index.php without need to refresh?

Comment: `data-ajax="false"` means non-Ajax navigation as you've mentioned. Place jQuery and jQuery-Mobile in head section of options.php.

Comment: They already are in head section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add additional code to your logout.php file to execute after the logout code executes. PHP headers can accomplish this. Within your PHP tags, add this to the end of your code:

header( 'Location: http://mywebsite/index.php' ) ;